# How to load logging.xml file from resources folder in project in Jboss

Tags: java, file, jboss, filenotfoundexception, absolute-path

I'm working on a webapp in `JbossEAP` in Jboss DevStudio.

I have a `logging.xml` file which is present in `src/main/resources` folder in the project and I added resources folder to buildpath of project.

I'm trying to get the absolute path of that file inside a class.

No matter what method I try for that, it is considering the base folder as the bin folder in the Jboss EAP.

If I try to load using `File("logging.xml")`, it is trying to get from `C:\DEVTOOLS\redhat\EAP6.4.0\bin\logging.xml` and not from project's `basedirectory/src/main/resources` folder and throwing `FileNotFoundException`.

I just want the absolute path of that .xml file.

How do I get the root directory of the project and refer `.xml` from there (or any other method to get the path of file) instead of bin folder of server?

Comment: Use relative path: getClassLoader().getResource(), then try to get absolute path of File (using java.nio)

Comment: tried that already. It is checking in WEB-INF/classes folder only and not in WEB-INF/classes/main/resources/ where the actual file is present.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a Maven project structure for a non-Maven project. You could change your project to use Maven or a compatible build tool such as Gradle, but the easiest fix is to simply move your file from `src/main/resources` to `src`. You can then delete `src/main/resources`.